# Can't create user post in django

Tags: python, django, post, model

I'm trying to create a post using the User profile instance. The post is saved but there is no object created in the database

In my user_blog app i have created Profile model for user

**blog_users/models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify
# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics/', blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have created Post model in separate app (posts)

**posts/models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from blog_users.models import Profile
# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='user_post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=False)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.profile.user.username} | post"
```

**posts/forms.py**

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms import forms

from .models import Post

class CreatePost(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
          
            'title',
            'content',
            'slug',
            
        ]
```

**posts/views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import CreatePost
from blog_users.models import Profile
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
@login_required(login_url='account_login')
def create_post(request):
    
    current_user = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = CreatePost(instance=current_user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreatePost(request.POST, instance=current_user)
        if form.is_valid():       
            form.save()
            print('success')
            return redirect(f"/blog_users/{request.user}")
    
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/create_post.html', context)
```

In **posts/views.py** file, i have used `print('success')` after `form.save()`. Even `success` is printed in the console, no object is created in the database. If i use  `form = CreatePost(request.POST)` in **posts/views.py** instead of  `form = CreatePost(request.POST, instance=current_user)` it results in  `NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_post.title`. I don't know why it is happens.

I can't upadate existing post i have directly created in database and i can't create new post. In which line i have mistaken, please help me to find the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide CreatePost form

Comment: `CreatePost` is a form for the `Post` model **not** the `Profile` model hence passing it a profile instance is _wrong_.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam i have already provided sir

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ok, please edit my code in comment

Answer (score 0):

`CreatePost` is a form for the `Post` model not the `Profile` model hence passing it a profile instance is wrong. Instead you need to modify the *instance* wrapped by the form to set the foreign key to `profile`. Also from the error `NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_post.title` it seems you are not providing a value for the title? Your field `title` is not nullable hence you need to provide a value for that. Make changes to your code like so:

```
@login_required(login_url='account_login')
def create_post(request):
    current_user = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = CreatePost()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreatePost(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.profile = current_user # Set profile here
            form.save()
            print('success')
            return redirect(f"/blog_users/{request.user}")
    
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/create_post.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: `redirect` can take the url name and kwargs to create the url by itself. Hence instead of creating the url using string
> formatting you should use that. See the
> [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

Comment: i have provided value to the title. But the error occurs again

Answer (score 0):

problem solved i have made some validation error in `forms.py` file.  So i have corrected it..then`NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_post.title` is cleared . thank you